# Azure web role deploy does not copy non-project files

Tags: azure

We are trying to deploy an AngularJs website to azure that is build with gulp. So we develop in a source application and gulp copies the files to the dist project. The dist project is a Azure cloud source Web Role. The "compiled" files are inside of the project folder, though for some reason they are not copied.

We turned on the option *Properties* -> *Package/Publich Web* -> *All files in this project folder*

After deploying I only see the packes.config, web.config and bin folder. Is there anything we need to do to get the rest of the files deployed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, gulp generated files are not actually part of the project (included in the xx.csproj file) which is why "All files..." does not work. We accomplish this by adding some custom targets for build to the project file - our gulp files are in a folder called "dist".

Unload Project >> Edit... then include something like:

```xml
  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_DistFiles Include="dist\**\*" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_DistFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>dist\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
      <_SrcFiles Include="src\**\*" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_SrcFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>src\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
.
.
.
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="CustomCollectFiles">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(_DistFiles)" DestinationFolder="dist" />
  </Target>
```