# Azure WebRole: include static assets when deploying via VisualStudio

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles

Is that possible to include extra files (not included in ASP.NET / WebRole project) when deploying to Azure Cloud Services?

The project is a Single Page Application, I need to include ~500 kb of static files (mainly JavaScript and CSS); using CDN in that case sounds a bit like overkill.

When deploying standard ASP.NET to a remote IIS, I've included these files by simply extending publication profile settings (pubxml) with CustomCollectFiles.

I have no idea however how to include the files when deploying to Cloud Services

Answer (score 0):

By default CustomCollectFiles won't work for you but with a tad bit of change to your .csproj you can support this

As per [Azure web role deploy does not copy non-project files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530421/azure-web-role-deploy-does-not-copy-non-project-files)

```
<Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_DistFiles Include="dist\**\*" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_DistFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>dist\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
      <_SrcFiles Include="src\**\*" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_SrcFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>src\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
.
.
.
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="CustomCollectFiles">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(_DistFiles)" DestinationFolder="dist" />
  </Target>
```

Another option could be to include those files are linked files/folders if that should work.